# Unwanted Data Manipulation Using Processing's textSize() Method

Tags: java, processing

The application displays streams of randomly changing characters, running down the page to achieve a matrix like effect. The app uses Processing tools to achieve this. Everything works fine, except calling textSize() changes the text size, but the characters are now all turned into 0 or square like characters as shown in the below image.

[image]

I have recreated a smaller hard coded version to recreate the problem. This version simply draws a Symbol object in the middle of the screen. The character does not change and does not move.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Main extends PApplet {
    private Symbol symbol;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("Main");
    }

    public void setup() {
        noCursor();
        background(0);
        symbol = new Symbol(this, width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    public void settings() {
        fullScreen();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        symbol.show();
    }

    public static int getRandomInt(final int min, final int max) {
        return (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
    }

    public class Symbol {
        private float xPosition;
        private float yPosition;
        private char symbol;
        private PApplet parent;
        private float size = 35f;
        private int opacity = 255;

        public Symbol(final PApplet parent,
                      final float xPosition,
                      final float yPosition) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.xPosition = xPosition;
            this.yPosition = yPosition;
            // Sets symbol to a random Katakana character.
            this.symbol = generateRandomSymbol(0x30A0, 96);
        }

        public char generateRandomSymbol(final int origin, final int bound) {
            return (char) (origin + getRandomInt(0, bound));
        }

        public void show() {
            parent.fill(155, 155, 155, opacity);
            // TODO: Fix this dumb bug
            // parent.textSize(size);
            parent.text(symbol, xPosition, yPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

The entire project was a bit large to include in this post so here is the projects github repo page: https://github.com/JSextonn/MatrixRain

Any explanations on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right to not include your entire project. But please post your code as a [mcve] that we can actually run. In this case a simple sketch that shows some hard-coded text without any movement would be enough to show your problem.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have included a runnable example and tried to minimalize the code as much as I could. Hope this snippet is a bit more useful.

Comment: Thanks for posting the simpler example. This looks like a bug. I've created a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4956), hopefully we hear back from the Processing devs. (Also check out the even smaller example program in that issue!)

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for creating the issue, ill have to keep on the lookout for patches. And yea that example is definitely bare bones, something was telling me I wasnt going to be able to replicate the bug if I made it that simple, for whatever reason. Thanks again.